# FaceBook SDK, FBSession actions

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on an iOS App that will integrate FB SDK.
Now i'm following the sample codes FB has, and the way the Class FBSession works is unclear to me.
I fully understand the login process the only problem is in the log-out process.

In the FBLoginCustomUISample sample code, there is a method to log in/out the user.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender
{
  // If the session state is any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
  if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpen
      || FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateOpenTokenExtended) {

    // Close the session and remove the access token from the cache
    // The session state handler (in the app delegate) will be called automatically
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];

  // If the session state is not any of the two "open" states when the button is clicked
  } else {
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
    // You must ALWAYS ask for public_profile permissions when opening a session
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"]
                                       allowLoginUI:YES
                                  completionHandler:
     ^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

       // Retrieve the app delegate
       AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
       // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
       [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
     }];
  }
}
```

Whenever i log into the app it all goes well and the login alert view comes on.
Now when i press the button again to logout, it calls the

```
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

but after it completes this method the code skips to the second part of the if-else statement, and execute the

```
   AppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
   // Call the app delegate's sessionStateChanged:state:error method to handle session state changes
   [appDelegate sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
```

The sessionStateChanged:state:error: is a method that handles the session state (i don't want to add it cuz it's long, but it can be viewed in the sample code).
My question is why does it goes to the second part of the if-else

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

[From documentation:](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/class/FBSession/#openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions%3aallowLoginUI%3acompletionHandler%3a)

```
handler 
Many applications will benefit from notification when a session becomes invalid or undergoes other state transitions. If a block is provided, the FBSession object will call the block each time the session changes state.
```

So, you shouldn't get rid of method `sessionStateChanged...` because it's necessary to have actual information about your `FBSession` and this block with this method will be called anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The fact that the session called the completion handler whenever the state changes is clear, but it is not a good behaviour to have. I have other app related code in the completion handler, and I don't want that code to run twice